# Save data from config file to db (Laravel 5.3)

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel

I have a file **messages** in my config folder as

```
'msg_log' => [
        'created' => 'created successfully',
        'not_created' => 'not created',
```

]
i have a table in DB as **messages** there are two fields as **type** where should go created if its created or notcreated if not created and other field is **msg** there should go message 
how can i save this to my messages table from store method in controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{


    $data['email']            = $request->input('email');
    $data['password']         = bcrypt($request->input('password'));

     $user = User::create($data);
     if($user->id) {
        // If Created Here
     }else{
        // Not created 

     }
```

please tell me how to do in if else to save that **type** and **msg** in message table 
Thank

Comment: what is your config file name ? might be [this](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/ho-to-access-config-variables-in-laravel-5?page=1) can help you.

Comment: i ma getting message but not know how to get  `'created' => 'created successfully', ` created in above to store in DB mean already getting created successfully not getting created keyword

Comment: config file name is messages.php

Answer (score 0):

You should try this

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
  $data['email']         = $request->input('email');
  $data['password']      = bcrypt($request->input('password'));
   if(User::create($data)) {
    // If Created Here
   }else{
    // Not created 
   }
}
```

Comment: integrity constraint issue .. But i solve myself in different way Thanks